# MutationObserver when node is inserted

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I'd like to add a node element when a node is well inserted in the dom.

When I call the `observe` method I get an error : `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

My code :

```
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver( function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach( function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation);
    // here I'd like to insert my new node
  });
});

var options = {
  childList: true
};

var targetNode = document.querySelector('div.nav-bar');
console.log(targetNode); //null - and not null after dom ready
mutationObserver.observe(targetNode, options);
```